# Comma separated values grouping based on set of strings using regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a question I am hoping someone could help with...

This is input string

```
Lopes de Carvalho, L., Structural Bioinformatics Laboratory, Biochemistry, Faculty of Science and Engineering, √Öbo Akademi University, Turku, Finland; Bligt-Lind√©n, E., Structural Bioinformatics Laboratory, Biochemistry, Faculty of Science and Engineering, √Öbo Akademi University, Turku, Finland; Ramaiah, A., Structural Bioinformatics Laboratory, Biochemistry, Faculty of Science and Engineering, √Öbo Akademi University, Turku, Finland, Sri Paramakalyani Centre for Environmental Sciences, Manonmaniam Sundaranar University, Alwarkurichi, Tamil Nadu  627412, India; Johnson, M.S., Structural Bioinformatics Laboratory, Biochemistry, Faculty of Science and Engineering, √Öbo Akademi University, Turku, Finland; Salminen, T.A., Structural Bioinformatics Laboratory, Biochemistry, Faculty of Science and Engineering, √Öbo Akademi University, Turku, Finland;
```

The pattern is like

```
<author name>., <author meta>; <pattern repeats> 

<author meta> => from this, need group the values by any one of the comma separated value matches first, which contains the string university|college|institute
```

Let take the first portion of the give string

```
Lopes de Carvalho, L., Structural Bioinformatics Laboratory, Biochemistry, Faculty of Science and Engineering, √Öbo Akademi University, Turku, Finland;
```

Need a grouping like
Match 1:
Group 1. Lopes de Carvalho, L `based on ., separator`
Group 2. Structural Bioinformatics Laboratory, Biochemistry, Faculty of Science and Engineering,
Group 3. √Öbo Akademi University `first match which contains the given set of strings (i.e) university`
Group 4. Turku, Finland

Match 2:
Group 1. Ramaiah, A.
Group 2. Structural Bioinformatics Laboratory, Biochemistry, Faculty of Science and Engineering,
Group 3. √Öbo Akademi University `first match which contains the given set of strings (i.e) university`
Group 4. Turku, Finland, Sri Paramakalyani Centre for Environmental Sciences, Manonmaniam Sundaranar University, Alwarkurichi, Tamil Nadu  627412, India

From this group 2, 3, 4 I can't able figure out how to construct the regular expression.

This is my try

```
(.*?)\., ([^,]*)(.*?);
```

https://regex101.com/r/I7xjlx/1

I have a tried a number of ways of doing this but cannot work out the best way to go about constructing the regular expression.

Comment: Are there always 4 groups in each match? There's no way to have a variable number of groups returned by a regexp.

Comment: Each `()` in the regexp can only produce one group in the results..

Comment: @Barmar Yes, we need 4 groups so that I will rearrange university name after the author, followed by group 2 and group 4 using javascript

Worst case I thought,  `(.*?)\., ([^,]*)(.*?);` group 2 -  split by comma and check values contains university, then rearrange.

Comment: If there are 4 groups, your regexp should have 4 `(...)`.

Comment: To match a substring that contains a given set of strings, you need to use a lookahead. But I'm not sure how to use that here. Do you have to do this using regexp? It would be much easier if you use `split()` and then tested each element.

Comment: yes we should have (...) but I don't know how to split into 4 groups

group2: <group before comma where the first occurrence of the given substrings>.   
group3: in between comma for the first occurrence of the given substrings.   
group4: group after comma where the first occurrence of the given substrings.

Comment: `string.split(';')` will split the long string at `;`. Then use `split(',')` to split each substring at commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression matches the words that are case insensitive "university|college|institute" and occurs at the **end** of the matching group followed by a comma. For example: `, √Öbo Akademi University, ...` but not `, University of √Öbo Akademi, ...`.

Furthermore, after the third group, if one word in the set occurs again, it won't capture. As in:

```
Turku, Finland, Sri Paramakalyani Centre for Environmental Sciences, Manonmaniam Sundaranar --> University <--, Alwarkurichi, Tamil Nadu 627412, India
```

---

#### Regex

`/(.*?\.), (.*?)(?:, )([^,]+(?<=university|college|institute)), (.*?); /gi`

Explanation of the RegExp:

- `(.*?\.),`  : anything until a `.` followed by `,`  (1st group)
- `(.*?)(?:, )`: anything until a `,`  which comes before the third group (2nd group)
- `([^,]+(?<=university|college|institute))`: anything before one word of the given set until first comma from back to front (3rd group)
- `, (.*?);`: anything after `,`  until `;` (4th group)

Flags:

- `g`: global
- `i`: insensitive

As shown here: [RegExp](https://regex101.com/r/C5T09f/1)

Comment: Is there any possibility group 2 to 2 parts. like this 

Group 2. Structural Bioinformatics Laboratory, Biochemistry, Faculty of Science and Engineering,

Group 3. √Öbo Akademi University

https://regex101.com/r/ZkojrN/2

Comment: Do you mean separating group 2 from 3? I've updated my answer. Can you check it now, please?